# Conversion failed when converting date from character string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @count varchar(max)
Select @count=configurable from configurableitems where project='auto'
Delete from detaillog where createdtime<convert(date,getdate()-@count)
```

I am getting error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

Comment: The above really doesn't make any sense. You declare `@Count` as a `varchar(MAX)`, and the try to subtract said value from `GETDATE()`. Dates and strings are *completely* different values. It makes no sense to substract a `varchar` that is up to *2 billion* characters long from a `datetime` value.

Comment: Earlier we use query like :Delete from detaillog where createdtime<convert(date,getdate()-30)

Comment: That query is in your question, however, that doesn't explain why you are trying to subject an up to 2Gigabyte string from a `datetime`... What are you *really* trying to achieve here. Dates aren't strings, they are stored as binary values. Adding and subtracting from them doesn't make sense. Instead, if you want to add, or subtract a interval from a date and time value, use `DATEADD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the above doesn't make much sense. Substracting an up to 2 billion character `varchar` value from a `datetime`, is nonsensical. With a name like `@Count` that implies a numerical value too. Perhaps `@count` should be a `int`?

Next, adding and subtracting on dates doesn't make lot of sense. What is `2020-12-06T13:05:00:123 - 3` for example? Minus 3 *what*? Although this syntax works with the older `(small)datetime` data types, it does not for the new date and time data types. If you want to add/subtract intervals from your date and time values use `DATEADD`.

Perhaps what you want is this:

```sql
DECLARE @count int;

SELECT @count = configurable
FROM configurableitems
WHERE project = 'auto';

DELETE FROM detaillog
WHERE createdtime < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY,-@Count,GETDATE());
```